# Cannot set the timezone of Postgresql role

Tags: postgresql

[The official Postgresql recognized timezones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/timezones.html) says Iran Time is `IT` so why I get this error? It's version 12 if matters.

```
postgres=# alter role myuser set timezone to 'IT';
ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "IT"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't read the manual of outdated and discontinued versions. The fact that the page doesn't exist any longer for supported versions should have made you suspicious.

Modern Postgres versions provide the view [pg_timezone_names](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-timezone-names.html) to check for valid timezone names.

If you [run](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6beb8f5f526ecdf5521535fd953a66c4)

```
select *
from pg_timezone_names
where name ilike '%iran%'
```

you will get this result:

| name | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Europe/Tirane | CET | 01:00:00 | f |
| posix/Europe/Tirane | CET | 01:00:00 | f |
| posix/Iran | +0330 | 03:30:00 | f |
| Iran | +0330 | 03:30:00 | f |

so there is no such abbreviation (any more). You will need to use the name:

```
alter role myuser set timezone to 'Iran';
```

---

Note that the result also depends on the operating system on which the Postgres server is running. On Windows you wouldn't get the `posix` time zones.